# How can I make inlay hints in VS Code only show up when holding ctrl+alt?

Tags: visual-studio-code

[what I currently see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NLdRm.png)

This is default I want when Ctrl + Alt is hold then vs code shows types of variables and I want to enable permanently: [expected result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/awNqA.png).

Answer (score 0):

Put this in your [settings.json file](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings#_settingsjson):

```json
"editor.inlayHints.enabled": "offUnlessPressed",
```

The description for this setting+value combination:

> Enables the inlay hints in the editor.
>
> `offUnlessPressed`: Inlay hints are hidden by default and show when holding Ctrl+Alt

Note that on macOS, "Alt" is the option key.

For your reference / learning purposes, you could also have found this info by googling "`vscode toggle inlay hints while key is held`", which would probably have turned up [this video by VS Code maintainer Matt Bierner](https://youtu.be/uvrIFZYW7eg).

Comment: For dart flutter
i got options for JS & TS